# Querying multiple table columns with the the same id but reversing them

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I have a `to` and `from` columns which are integers from the `users` in my messages table, as I was building a chat like application on this part.

So I want to fetch all the messages of the currently logged on user. so this is the query

```
    $all_messages = Message::where('from',$logged_user)->orWhere('to',$logged_user)->with('owner')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

note that `$logged_user` variable is an integer / the authenticated users id
so from that,

but also I want to get also the messages between the `logged_user` and also the `respondent_id` or the id of the respondent or the user that I am trying to connect also.

So for example the currently logged on user_id is `2` and the respondent id is 3 I want the messages that have a `from` of 2 or 3 and also the `respondent_id` of 2 and 3 something like that

Comment: $all_messages = Message::where('from',$logged_user)->orWhere('to',$logged_user)->with('owner')->with('from')->with('to')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

Comment: Can you please explain 2 me what does this code does @JoseCarlosRamírezVásquez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the question right you're looking for the messages belonging to the conversation between two users, so what you're looking for should be following:

```php
$loggedInUserId = 2;
$contactUserId = 3;

$messages = Message::query()
    ->where(function ($query) use ($loggedInUserId, $contactUserId) {
        $query->where('sender_id', $loggedInUserId)
              ->where('recipient_id', $contactUserId);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($loggedInUserId, $contactUserId) {
        $query->where('recipient_id', $loggedInUserId)
              ->where('sender_id', $contactUserId);
    })
    ->with('owner')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Also, if you're heavily relying on having to track "conversations" between two or more users you might think to aggregate them as threads.